# mercurial cloned data inegrity

Tags: mercurial, java

I'm cloning openJDK source code to my local repo, and I'd like be sure that the file integrity has been maintained in transit.

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/
```

The Mercurial FAQ says that revlogs are checked against their hashes, "But this alone is not enough to ensure that someone hasn't tampered with a repository. For that, you need cryptographic signing." Does that mean I need to use 
SSH like this?

```
hg clone ssh://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/
```

And to get SSH access, do I have to sign up as a contributor to the project? If so, is there a way to get a verified clone without becoming a contributor?

Answer (score 1):

SSH provides *transport encryption*. It ensures the data cannot be altered in-transit from the OpenJDK repository to your computer.

The Mercurial FAQ is talking about [*signing the commits*](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommitSigningPlan), which ensures that you can later verify that these commits have not been tampered with *individually*. It means an attacker cannot break into the OpenJDK servers or falsify a commit for upstream acceptance,  adding in revisions that the project doesn't mean to be there. You would be able to recognise such revisions because they lack the right signature or are not signed at all.

SSH wouldn't protect you against such issues, because SSH doesn't care about the data it transfers. Malicious (altered or added) commits are transferred just as securely as valid revisions.

Signed commits is not something you as a *consumer* of the repository can add later. The OpenJDK project would have to build signing into their committing procedure from the start.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, yes, in-transit security is what I'm concerned about. It sounds like I misinterpreted the Mercurial FAQ.  When I attempt to clone using SSH, I get this response: remote: "Permission denied (publickey). abort: no suitable response from remote hg!". Given that response, what's the best way to get a secure clone of openJDK?

Comment: @kitakitsune: SSH requires that you have an account on the server (GitHub gives you this if you supply them your public key). The other option is to use HTTPS, but I see that OpenJDK doesn't offer that for their Mercurial server. There is a [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror), with both HTTPS and SSH options to pull a clone. Question then is, is the process that pushes the mirror to GitHub secure?